# Trying to HEAD request a list of websites from an Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have a large list of websites in a csv or xslx file that I need to check the error code each website spits out. I think using requests is my best bet but that's as far as I'm getting.

I'm basically all pseudocode at this point so I haven't tried to run anything

The example below is something I found that I'm trying to work on top of which works great for individual websites. I know I have to replace ("http://www.google.com") with the list from excel which is where I'm stuck.

```
import requests

resp = requests.head("http://www.google.com")

print resp.status_code, resp.text, resp.headers
```

I have some code snippets saved for getting stuff out of the excel file but it doesn't seem like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Load the csv into a list, `csvList = list(csv.reader(open(path)))` then iterate that list

```
for row in csvList:
    for cell in row:
        resp = requests.head(cell)
        print (cell)
        print (resp)
```